# Android MVVM Jetpack navigation component with coroutine

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to implement the android jetpack navigation component.
The case is almost the same as in the official doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional

But my case is, if the user hasn't logged in yet where the login access will be recorded in the database (Room),
then the system will force the user to login.
I use https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action to declare
destination to the login fragment

[image: Navigation]

Then in order, the definition is as follows

1. Home Fragment is startDestination,
2. If no user data has been found in the database, display the login page
3. If the login is successful, bring the user back to home and save data login to database.

I use MVVM Architecture and Coroutine which runs requests to REST
using Retrofit.

Here are some code that I used:

1. Navigation (xml)

   ```
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav"
        app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
            android:name="com.depo.trask.ui.home.HomeFragment"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">

            <argument android:name="authentication"
                android:defaultValue="none" />

            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_settingsFragment"
                app:destination="@id/settingsFragment" />

        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
            android:name="com.depo.trask.ui.settings.SettingsFragment"
            android:label="@string/settings" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
            android:name="com.depo.trask.ui.login.LoginFragment"
            android:label="fragment_login"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_global_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="false"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </navigation>
   ```
2. MainActivity

   ```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private lateinit var navController: NavController
        private lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
        private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
        private val navigationInMainScreen = setOf(
            R.id.loginFragment,
            R.id.homeFragment,
            R.id.containerShippingFragment,
            R.id.locationFragment,
            R.id.historyFragment,
            R.id.aboutFragment
        )

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyTheme)
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            setupNavController()
        }

        override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
            navController.navigateUp()
            return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
        }

        // Nav Controller
        private fun setupNavController() {

            navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
            setupActionBar()
            setupBottomNavigationBar()

            navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->

                // Listening toolbar
                when(destination.id){
                    R.id.loginFragment, R.id.aboutFragment -> toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
                    else -> toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }

                // Listening bottom navigation bar
                when (destination.id) {
                    R.id.loginFragment, R.id.settingsFragment -> bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
                    else -> bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }

        // Top Bar OR App Bar
        private fun setupActionBar() {
            toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
            val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
                navigationInMainScreen
            )
            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        }

        // Bottom Navigation Bar
        private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
            bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view)
            bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        }
    }
   ```
3. Home Fragment

   ```
    class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

        ?? Should I usede LoginViewModel ?

        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        }

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            observeAuthenticationState()
        }

        private fun observeAuthenticationState() {
            val navController = findNavController()

            // REDIRECT USER TO LOGIN PAGE ?
            // How To check it
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_loginFragment)
        }   
    }
   ```
4. Login Fragment

   ```
    class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

        private lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel // How can I shared this to home fragment
        private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginBinding

        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {

            // For Retrofit
            val networkConnectionInterceptor = NetworkConnectionInterceptor(requireContext())
            val api = MyApi(networkConnectionInterceptor)

            // For Room
            val db = AppDatabase(context = requireActivity().applicationContext)

            // For ViewModel
            val repository = UserRepository(api, db)
            val factory = LoginViewModelFactory(repository)

            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater,
                R.layout.fragment_login,
                container,
                false
            )

            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
            binding.buttonLogin.setOnClickListener { loginUser() }
            return binding.root
        }

        private fun loginUser() {
            val username = binding.editTextUsername.text.toString().trim()
            val password = binding.editTextPassword.text.toString().trim()

            binding.progressBar.show()
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                try {
                    val loginResponse = viewModel.userLogin(username!!, password!!)

                    if(loginResponse.user != null){
                        viewModel.saveLoggedInUser(loginResponse.user)
                    }

                    binding.progressBar.hide()
                    binding.root.context.toast(loginResponse.message!!)

                } catch (e: ApiException) {
                    binding.progressBar.hide()
                    binding.root.context.toast( e.toString())
                } catch (e: NoInternetException) {
                    binding.progressBar.hide()
                    binding.root.context.toast( e.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```

My question ?

1. How to force users to log in fragments correctly on home fragments?
2. How to use LoginViewModel on HomeFragment?